# ¿En qué estoy fallando?, estoy intentando hacer la sucesión de Fibonacci

Tags: java

**¿Alguien sabe en qué estoy fallando o qué tengo que hacer?**

Quiero hacer la sucesión de Fibonaccien Java, hice el siguiente código:

```
public class Fibonacci{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cu = 0;
        while(cu < 2048){
            int a = 1;
            int b = 1;
            int  co = 0;
            cu = co;
            co = a + b;
            System.out.println(co);
            a = b;
            b = co;
        }
    }
}
```

> Pero obtengo como resultado:

2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2

Comment: Intenta indentar mejor tu código, no se entiende completamente. Esa la idea de usar la [indentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n). También intenta usar nombres de variables más amigables. No te cobran por los caracteres usados. Son consejos de buenas prácticas.  Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos, tengo el identado en mi código pero no conozco del todo como redactar el código si que lo pierda en Stack Overflow. Es la primera vez que pregunto algo aquí.

Comment: Primero que nada, es Fibonacci jaja, segundo, tu problema está en que las variables ```a```, ```b``` y ```co``` están inicializadas dentro del bucle ```while```. Es decir, en cada iteración tendrás ```a = 1```, ```b = 1```, ```co = 0``` y a la hora de sumar ```a + b``` siempre tendrás ```1 + 1```. Si las inicializas fuera del bucle ```while``` no deberías tener este problema.

Comment: El problema es a y b son definidas dentro del bucle while... con lo que valen 1 al inicio de cada iteración

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No soy experto en java, mas bien solo se la sintaxis básica, pero creo que el problema está en que la variable a y b se definen siempre como 1 y 1 al estar dentro del `while`. Creo que si las defines antes, se resolverá tu problema.

```
    public class Fibanocci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cu = 0;
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int  co = 0;
        while(cu < 2048){
            co = a + b;
            cu = co;
            a = b;
            b = co;
            System.out.println(co);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a la descripciòn de la secuencia de Fibonacci:

> F(n) = F(n–2) + F(n–1) donde n ≥ 2. Cada término de la secuencia
> después de los dos primeros, es la suma de los dos términos previos.
> Esta secuencia de números fue primero creada por Leonardo Fibonacci in
> 1202.

Por lo que la secuencìa serìa:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144 ...
```

el problema es que las variables se estan reasignando en el bucle y b debe ser inicializada con valor 0:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       
    int cu = 0;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;
    int  co = 0;
     
    while(cu < 2048){
        cu = co;
        co = a + b;
        
        a = b;
        b = co;
        System.out.println(co);
    }
}
```

la salida serìa:

```
1                                          
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597                                               
2584
4181
```